# If $\alpha\implies\beta$ and $\beta\implies\alpha$ are satisfiable, then $\alpha\iff \beta$ must be satisfiable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Consider this sentence:

> If $\alpha\implies\beta$ and $\beta\implies\alpha$ are satisfiable,
> then $\alpha\iff \beta$ is satisfiable.

I think the above sentence is correct because

$$\alpha\iff \beta\equiv   (\alpha\implies\beta)\wedge (\beta\implies\alpha).$$

Is my argument valid?

Comment: Why do you think that $P \land Q$ needs to be satisfiable if $P$ and $Q$ are satisfiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $\alpha\implies\beta$ and $\beta\implies\alpha$ are satisfiable,
> then $\alpha\iff \beta$ is satisfiable.

This is false: for a counterexample, just let $\beta=\lnot\alpha.$

(On the other hand, the disjunction of two satisfiable sentences is indeed satisfiable, and the conjunction or disjunction of two validities is indeed a validity.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence isn't necessarily correct.

Let $\beta \equiv \neg \alpha$. For interpretation $I$ for which $I(\alpha) = 1$, you'd get $I(\beta) = 0$, and therefore $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$ is satisfied by interpretation $I$.

Analogous to that, interpretation $J$ for which $J(\alpha) = 0$ satisfies $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$.

However, for every interpretation where $\alpha$ is true, $\beta$ is false, so $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ is never satisfied.